# MS SQL Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, sql-server, rubygems

I need to write a ruby script to connect to an MS SQL Server database, but all of the threads I've found point to gems to tie ActiveRecord into MS SQL. Are there any gems that will let me do this similar to pg (for postgres https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg)? I just need to do some really simple remote queries, thanks so much!

Comment: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to do it is using the tiny_tds gem https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds