# Parsing XML then inserting into Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, ruby, xml, parsing

I tried to to Google this but haven't had any luck.  My question is in two related parts:

1. I'm trying to parse an XML file of student absences that eventually can be inserted into a Microsoft SQL Server data-warehouse using Ruby. I found I can parse using Ruby's REXML library. I also looked into Nokogiri.
2. I'm stuck figuring out what to do with the parsed information. I have to insert it into a Microsoft SQL Server but I can't find any documentation on how to insert it.

Here's a subset of the XML file I'm working with:

```
<data name="Export_AbsenceInfo copy" time="2013-12-04 20:35:00Z" xmlns="">
  <row conf="89059661" absence_instance_id="129549898" created="6/28/2012" date="7/5/2012"                        
    employee_identifier="MichelleTeacher" school_external_id="901" school_name="Training Port                                                 
    City Academy"    substitute_identifier="" start_time_absence="7:30:00 AM" 
    end_time_absence="4:00:00 PM" filled="No" absence_reason="Sick Day" 
    approval_status="Unapproved" approved_by="" duration_absence="8.50" reconciled_date=""reconciled="No" />
  <row conf="89065127" absence_instance_id="129560459" created="6/29/2012" date="7/2/2012"
    employee_identifier="EmmileTeacher" school_external_id="902" school_name="Training Langston
    Hughes Academy" substitute_identifier="" start_time_absence="7:30:00 AM"       
    end_time_absence="4:00:00 PM" filled="No" absence_reason="Bereavement"
    approval_status="Unapproved" approved_by="" duration_absence="8.50" reconciled_date=""reconciled="No" />
</data>
```

The method below is something I tried, thanks to The Tin Man:

```
require 'Nokogiri'

def parse(file)
  xmlfile = File.open('AesopAbsences.xml')
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(xmlfile)
  data = doc.search.map do |row|
    Hash[row.attributes.keys.zip(row.attributes.values.map(&:value))]
  end
end

parse('AesopAbsences.xml')
```

Nothing seems to be returning after line 4.  When I try a `puts` statements, I'm not getting The Tin Man's solution.

Any direction would be awesome!

---

Finished script just in case people want to know how this was solved with the sequel gem.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'Sequel'

class Absence

  def initialize (args)
    @database = Sequel.connect("sqlite://#{args}.db")
  end

  def parse(file)
      xmlfile = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open(file))
      data = xmlfile.search('row').map do |row|
        Hash[row.attributes.keys.zip(row.attributes.values.map(&:value))]
    end
  end


  def create_table(table_name)
    @database.create_table table_name do
      primary_key :id
      Integer :conf
      Integer :absence_instance_id
      String :created
      String :date
      String :employee_identifier
      Integer:school_external_id
      String :school_name
      String :substitute_identifier
      String :start_time_absence
      String :end_time_absence
      String :filled
      String :absence_reason
      String :approval_status
      String :approved_by
      Float :duration_absence
      String :reconciled_date
      String :reconciled
    end
  end

  def insert_table(table_name, xml_hash)
    testing = @database[table_name]
     xml_hash.each do |hash|
      testing.insert(hash)
    end
  end
end

#creates the database file after each new instance
absence = Absence.new("absencedb")

#parse for AesopAbsences.xml
parse = absence.parse('AesopAbsences.xml')

#creates table within the database
absence.create_table(:absencedata)

absence.insert_table(:absencedata, parse)
```

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried. What fields do you need? What format?

Comment: I'm suppose to get all fields.  The directions were a bit unclear, but just the ability to parse and insert into MS SQL.  I've never had to insert a file into a DB.  I've only had to create and migrate db through rails.

Comment: I include some code I actually tried but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "search" your code and compare it to what I wrote and see if you truly used it "verbatim".

Comment: You might also want to [read the documentation for `search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search).

Comment: Yea thanks, I forgot to insert the paramenter of 'row', but it's still returning an empty array.  I also changed Nokogiri::XML to Nokogiri:HTML but no luck.

Comment: Based on the XML you gave, the example code works correctly. Check your work carefully. If you still can't get it to work, edit your question and append your code to it. What you appended previously wasn't correct so we can't work from it. You also say that the XML in your question is a subset of the real XML. Perhaps it isn't an accurate subset?

Comment: Got it thanks...I worked on this for about 3 hours last night with a friend, and today paired with someone else.  Your code is correct and it works as is.  My friend tried it, and it worked for him when he put it into a method.  Then I said, okay, "let's figure this out character by character."  Thanks so much for the trouble.  My first stackoverflow post put me in the negatives.  Argh.  Next step is to put these into proper methods and classes so that the MS SQL can read it...which is all new to me, but hey, this is what programming is, right?

Comment: Take a *SERIOUS* look at the Sequel gem. It will make your task of working with the database much, much, easier. Ignore ranking for your account, and concentrate on asking good questions, that provide the information needed, and the points will accumulate. Then, once you're able to start helping others, do so with complete, well thought-out answers, and the points will grow faster. And, yes, this is programming, but you'll find patterns in the problems you want to solve, so remember the answers and improve on them and you'll do well.

Comment: The Tin Man, do you mind explaining offline (to prevent flooding the comments) two things.  1) Why it's not Nokogiri::XML instead Nokogiri::HTML.  I think Nokogiri::HTML defaults to searching an XML if it's not an html, but still..it makes sense code wise Nokogiri::XML.  2) How you used this line Hash[row.attributes.keys.zip(row.attributes.values.map(&:value))], especially what &:value is in the parameters.  I'm trying to piece that out in IRB but having some issues.

Comment: There is no "offline". Nokogiri uses more strict parsing rules when processing Nokogiri::XML than Nokogiri::HTML. That's because, by definition, XML is supposed to be a very strict standard, whereas, HTML has always been pretty sloppy about what's acceptable. `&:value` takes advantage of a "symbol to proc" method, introduced in Ruby 1.9, and previous to that in Rails. It's a shorthand for `map { |n| n.value }` and is a tiny bit slower but more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use regex for parsing the XML if the attributes of the XML are not too many(or not complex).

For MS SQL, you can check this stack question: [MS SQL Ruby Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961594/ms-sql-ruby-gem)

Comment: 8449 lines of XML of the same types so I'm not so sure if regex would be optimal here.  I'll look into this MS SQL Gem though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started with extracting the data. You'll need to figure out how to pass that to your database. I'll recommend looking at [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/index.html) to do that.

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<data name="Export_AbsenceInfo copy" time="2013-12-04 20:35:00Z" xmlns="">
  <row conf="89059661" absence_instance_id="129549898" created="6/28/2012" date="7/5/2012"
    employee_identifier="MichelleTeacher" school_external_id="901" school_name="Training Port
    City Academy"    substitute_identifier="" start_time_absence="7:30:00 AM"
    end_time_absence="4:00:00 PM" filled="No" absence_reason="Sick Day"
    approval_status="Unapproved" approved_by="" duration_absence="8.50" reconciled_date=""reconciled="No" />
  <row conf="89065127" absence_instance_id="129560459" created="6/29/2012" date="7/2/2012"
    employee_identifier="EmmileTeacher" school_external_id="902" school_name="Training Langston
    Hughes Academy" substitute_identifier="" start_time_absence="7:30:00 AM"
    end_time_absence="4:00:00 PM" filled="No" absence_reason="Bereavement"
    approval_status="Unapproved" approved_by="" duration_absence="8.50" reconciled_date=""reconciled="No" />
</data>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(xml)
data = doc.search('row').map{ |row|
  Hash[row.attributes.keys.zip(row.attributes.values.map(&:value))]
}
```

Which returns:

```
# => [{"conf"=>"89059661",
#      "absence_instance_id"=>"129549898",
#      "created"=>"6/28/2012",
#      "date"=>"7/5/2012",
#      "employee_identifier"=>"MichelleTeacher",
#      "school_external_id"=>"901",
#      "school_name"=>"Training Port\n    City Academy",
#      "substitute_identifier"=>"",
#      "start_time_absence"=>"7:30:00 AM",
#      "end_time_absence"=>"4:00:00 PM",
#      "filled"=>"No",
#      "absence_reason"=>"Sick Day",
#      "approval_status"=>"Unapproved",
#      "approved_by"=>"",
#      "duration_absence"=>"8.50",
#      "reconciled_date"=>"",
#      "reconciled"=>"No"},
#     {"conf"=>"89065127",
#      "absence_instance_id"=>"129560459",
#      "created"=>"6/29/2012",
#      "date"=>"7/2/2012",
#      "employee_identifier"=>"EmmileTeacher",
#      "school_external_id"=>"902",
#      "school_name"=>"Training Langston\n    Hughes Academy",
#      "substitute_identifier"=>"",
#      "start_time_absence"=>"7:30:00 AM",
#      "end_time_absence"=>"4:00:00 PM",
#      "filled"=>"No",
#      "absence_reason"=>"Bereavement",
#      "approval_status"=>"Unapproved",
#      "approved_by"=>"",
#      "duration_absence"=>"8.50",
#      "reconciled_date"=>"",
#      "reconciled"=>"No"}]
#      "reconciled"=>[]}]
```

For your purpose I'd change `map` to `each`, then put code inside that block that takes the retrieved `row` data and send that to the database for insertion.

Comment: see above for the code I tried verbatim.  Doesn't seem to like .search?

Comment: Well, if you used `search` correctly, like I did in my example, it would probably work better.